# Non-Schottky SiC diodes

Tags: diodes, schottky, pn-junction, buying, silicon

Hopefully this isn't too much of a shopping question. I am looking for off-the-shelf silicon carbide P-N junction diodes, but all I can find are Schottky ones. Do P-N version ones even exist commercially?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SiC pn diodes are not commercially manufactured for one simple reason:

They have a forward voltage of about 3 to 4 volts.

For almost any purpose, either a silicon pn diode or a SiC schottky is a better choice. Despite the famous leakiness of schottky diodes, SiC ones (due to the properties of silicon carbide) tend to have leakage currents more in line with the leakage of a silicon pn diode than a silicon schottky.

If, for some reason, you truly need a SiC pn diode, it may be possible to use the the body diode of a SiC MOSFET where you've tied gate to source. The gate-drain junction of a SiC JFET might work as well, though these are not usually rated for much if any forward current.

Comment: There are also BJTs, or there were, if you're so inclined; https://genesicsemi.com/sic-junction-transistor/GA10SICP12-263/GA10SICP12-263.pdf for example. Which could be B-E strapped, usable up to Vcbo and Ibmax.

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't think any of those are still manufactured, though. They were briefly useful in the rare cases you needed an all-SiC (for temperature ratings, probably) normally-off device, but now that you can get true SiC MOSFETs (and not just Si MOSFETs cascoded with SiC JFETs), their niche in the market is basically gone.